# How long can GET URL #anchor be?

Tags: url, anchor, maxlength

I'm trying to encode the state of webpage in #anchor by base64 encoding JSON string. Sometimes this string gets very long, 10KB for example. I'm not certain I can keep all this data in #anchor.

Does anyone know if #anchor is part of URL length definition?

- If it is then is it 2048? or is it 4096? There are conflicting answers about URL length.
- If it isn't then how much data can I put in #anchor?

Comment: For http Unlimited i belive,  but depending on the browser.

Comment: There is definitely limit. try copy-pasting URL a hundred times. Like `1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` followed by `2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222` It eventually blocks and you can't paste anymore. Hit limit.

Comment: 'depending on the browser',  the protocol is unlimited i belive,  it will just send more packages